# VBA excel filtering matching string before 1st '_' and matching string after the 2nd '_'

Tags: excel, vba, filter, partial-matches

I just started to learn VBA few days ago and trying to sort out a filtering problem and hope to get some idea.

I have a column of ID that the format is like "C_1_1", "C_1_11", "C_12_11".

The criteria was using the string before the first '*' symbol and string after second '*' symbol to find matching ID like head and tail e.g. "**C_***20***_2**" <-- "C_" and "*2". In VBA I tried to use Filter function to filter data that match "C*" then 2nd filter that match "_2"
[image]

However, the problem I am facing is that because the middle part of the ID is also in a format of "_xx" so there will be unwanted data like in the picture below that all the non-highlighted data is not relevant. Is there any suggestion I can filter or extract only the data in yellow colour? Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thank you so much.

[image]

Comment: If you don't mind using sheet auto filter, then maybe you can record the macro when manually doing a filter in column A using criteria1 _begins with_ and criteria2 _ends with_. Then modify the recorded macro into something like this : `inp1 = "=" & Range("H1") & "*": inp2 = "=*" & Range("H2")` .... `ActiveSheet.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=inp1, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:=inp2`

Comment: thank you i will give it a try and see how it goes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Filter Data

**Excel**

If you have Microsoft 365, without too much thinking, in cell `G2` you could simply use:

```vb
=FILTER(FILTER(A2:A100,LEFT(A2:A100,LEN(H2))=TEXT(H2,"@")),RIGHT(FILTER(A2:A100,LEFT(A2:A100,LEN(H2))=TEXT(H2,"@")),LEN(H3))=TEXT(H3,"@"))
```

**VBA**

```vb
Sub FilterData()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("Data")
    
    Dim sStr As String: sStr = CStr(ws.Range("H2").Value)
    Dim eStr As String: eStr = CStr(ws.Range("H3").Value)
        
    Dim rg As Range
    Set rg = ws.Range("A2", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    
    Dim Data(): Data = rg.Value
    
    Dim sr As Long, dr As Long, cString As String
    
    For sr = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
        cString = CStr(Data(sr, 1))
        If cString Like sStr & "*" & eStr Then
            dr = dr + 1
            Data(dr, 1) = cString
        End If
    Next sr
    
    With rg.EntireRow.Columns("G")
        .Resize(dr).Value = Data
        .Resize(ws.Rows.Count - .Row - dr + 1).Offset(dr).ClearContents
    End With

End Sub
```